# Make something happen on tab select with Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a project where I'm using tablayout using viewPager, following this nice tutorial https://medium.com/@eijaz/getting-started-with-tablayout-in-android-kotlin-bb7e21783761

The problem that I'm having is that once the views/fragments is instantiated there is nothing more happening in the views. They are truly static. I want to fill recycler views with data retrieved from a server. Not once, not twice, but every time the user presses some of the tabs.

I have tried to look for an answer, but I had no luck. Maybe the viewPager with fragments is not supposed to change after initialization?

-MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val fragmentAdapter = MyPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        viewpager_main.adapter = fragmentAdapter

        mainTabbedLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewpager_main)
    }
}
```

-MyPagerAdapter.kt

```
class MyPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {

    val fragmentList = listOf<Fragment>(ListFragment(), ScanFragment(), MinFragment(), SettingsFragment())

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        when (position) {
            0 -> {
                Log.d("Fragment", "Position: $position")
               return fragmentList[position]
            }
            1 -> {
                Log.d("Fragment", "Position: $position")
                return fragmentList[position]
            }
            2 -> {
                Log.d("Fragment", "Position: $position")
                return fragmentList[position]
            }
            3 -> {
                Log.d("Fragment", "Position: $position")
                return fragmentList[position]
            }
            else -> {
                throw IllegalArgumentException()
            }

        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return fragmentList.count()
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> "Liste"
            1 -> "Scan"
            2 -> "Min"
            3 -> "Settings"
            else -> {
                throw IllegalArgumentException()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

-ListFragment.kt

```
class ListFragment : Fragment() {

    val TAG = "ListFragment"

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false)

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated")

    }
}
```

In MyPagerAdapter.kt, setting the FragmentStatePagerAdapter (not FragmentPagerAdapter) made the views reload themselves if you press a tab far enough away, but that's not good enough. I have already made the app I want to create in iOS, where special functions always fires when visited in a tabbed layout. Is this not possible in this case?

Is there any way to force new initialization?